# Ctrl+\ hides all Cent Browser windows, but only when using Norwegian keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

When I press Ctrl and the key to the left of backspace (which outputs "\" on a Norwegian machine) all Cent Browser windows (on all desktops) are hidden. They don't show on the taskbar, nor in the alt-tab or Win+tab menus.

If I press the key combination again all windows appear again, on the current active desktop.

The strange thing is that I can't find any key combination that does the same thing when I use US keyboard layout, only when using Norwegian. Ctrl+`<the key to the left of right shift>` does nothing when using US layout.

I thought this was perhaps a universal Windows hotkey, but it seems to only affect Chrome and its window.

I would really like to disable this hotkey, since it can be pretty confusing when I hit this hotkey by mistake.

This issue just started a month or two ago, so I think it must have been a recent update to Chrome or Windows that caused it.

(Windows 10 1809)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have discovered the **Boss Key** feature of the Cent Browser.
This feature will quickly hide all browser windows and will bring back the
last activated window from before you started surfing.
It can optionally also mute all music that is currently being played
via the browser.

The idea is to enable you to surf on questionable websites at work, yet quickly
hide everything the moment your boss enters the room.
A second press will return you to where you stopped, once the boss has left the room.

This key is configurable in Settings. It is found in the section
"Under The Hood", sub-section "Boss key".
You may disable it or set it to some other key-combination
that is impossible to type by mistake.

---

[image]

---

Reference: [CentBrowser - Features](https://www.centbrowser.com/features.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use AutoHotkey to block the shortcut getting passed through.

```
; AutoHotKey script for disabling this shortcut (may or may not work)
^\::Return
```

The reason why

Ctrl+`<the key to the left of right shift>`

works on one layout and not the other is because on a standard US keyboard layout, the character to the left of delete is "+" or "=".

See here:
[image]

Whereas on your keyboard, it is "\". On a US keyboard, you can see the key is below backspace.